# Call Javascript function with parameters from C# Page .aspx

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have RegisterClientScriptBlock which is written inside page load of .aspx file `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

The Script actually gets ID From URL and then Pass it to openticketPageLoad() function of javascript.

**But it is not getting into openticketPageLoad() function. But .aspx page is loading.**

openTickets.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "openTicketsScript", "<script type=\'type/javascript\'>$(document).ready(function(){openticketPageLoad(" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + ");});</script>".ToString(), true);
}
}
```

Inside my javascript file

```
function openticketPageLoad(b)
{
alert(b); //No alert window coming.
}
```

Comment: Are you using an updatepanel?

Comment: No. Simple aspx file inherited from Master Page

Comment: Hmm I'd still suggest removing the `$(document).ready()` call, perhaps it's being executed after the initial `$(document).ready` call, sometimes resulting in it not being called at all. Another possibility is that you're overwriting `$(document).ready('different function')` somewhere.

Comment: @Destrictor removed `$(document).ready()` and check overwriting of function but still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following code:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
                "openTicketsScript", string.Format("openticketPageLoad({0});", Request.QueryString["ID"]), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

The last parameter is a boolean that specifies whether ASP.net should generate Script tags. As you already specify them I expect if you look at your source you are generating nested script tags.

Comment: Can you inspect the source using Firebug (or something similar) and post the output?

Comment: Used Firebug..in my opentickets.aspx page inside head tag i am unable to find following script 
`<script type=\'type/javascript\'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
openticketPageLoad('2');
});
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "openTicketsScript", "<script type=\'type/javascript\'>$(document).ready(function(){openticketPageLoad(" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + ");});</script>".ToString(), true);
```

Comment: Tried But doesnt seem to be worked. Its not getting into my javascript function

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do is assign the call to your javascript function direct in the load event of the body of the page. To assign the load function of the body from a content page can do the following:

```
HtmlGenericControl body = this.Master.FindControl("body") as HtmlGenericControl;
                body.Attributes.Add("onLoad", "openticketPageLoad(" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString() + ");");
```

And in the master page add the runat="server" to the body element:

```
<body id="body" runat="server">
```

I hope this helps.